# Can I write a file on the webhost's computer with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, writefile

I am trying to make an online game and I am using JavaScript on repl.it and I want to save the player's high score when they lose. I have a file called **high_scores.txt** that is in the same directory as my **script.js** file, and I want to write the player's score in the file if it is higher than another score. I have been reading and it seems that you can't write files to other computers, but I am trying to write a file on the computer that is hosting the website. Does someone know how to do this?

> Example: player's score = 145, files reads [563, 200, 76], this should write the player's score and make it [563, 200, 145] because it was bigger than that one

> Or... player's score = 145, files reads [563, 200, 76], this should write the player's score and make it [563, 200, 76, 145]

I just need some way to read and write the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not completely impossible ([saving files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file), [retrieving files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file)), but it's extremely cumbersome.

For what you're trying to accomplish, it would be far easier to read and save Local Storage, which saves the data persistently through the user's browser:

```
const oldHighScores = JSON.parse(localStorage.highScores || '[]');
// ... get newScore
const newHighScores = [...oldHighScores, newScore].sort((a, b) => a - b).slice(1);
localStorage.highScores = JSON.stringify(newHighScores);
```

Comment: will this allow other people to see your high scores, like, the file saves the top ten high scores out of everyone who has played? Because that is what I wanted

Comment: For communication between clients like that, you'll need to set up server-side logic, like a database and routes. It can't be done purely from a browser's `.js`.